# How to stack div elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a checker board using pure JavaScript, not jQuery. 
I have created the first row, but cannot seem to "stack" the rows to create a full board. If there is a better way to go about this than the road I'm going down, please enlighten me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Checkerboard</title>

        <style>
            .box {

                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                display: inline-block;

            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box"></div>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var row = function (node, count) {
    for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            copy = node.cloneNode(true);
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node).style.backgroundColor = "white";
        } else {
            copy = node.cloneNode(true);
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } 
}

}

row(document.querySelector('.box'), 8);

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: what is node ? where are you calling row function ?>

Comment: Seems to be a CSS issue, not javascript. Try something like putting a defined box around the outside, then put the divs inside with position relative.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, you just need to actually run the function you've created:

```
row(document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0], 50);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63dcjsk4/

**Edit**

If you're talking about the gap that appears between rows, fix this by using float and removing the inline-block display:

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63dcjsk4/1/